# How to run Minecraft on Debian 10 buster via Flatpak

Tags: debian, software-installation, minecraft

My problem was that there is no updated package on the https://mojang.com  site which can be run on the Debian 10 buster. The package you can get from the [official site][1] requires Java 8 JRE. But that Java version is obsolete, and is no longer supported by Debian 10.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! This is a Q&A site; could you please rephrase your post as a question and an answer? Thanks!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I deleted and undeleted this post just to ask you, because is not clear how to change it. Should I delete this post, or start a new one, just with the simple question, and then I have the posibility to answer on it? But I have no 15 reputation.

Comment: FYI, if you just want a minecraft-like game (and not necessarily minecraft itself), debian has the LGPL [minetest](https://www.minetest.net/) voxel game engine packaged.

Comment: :) thanks! I basically do not play. My daughter is playing Minecraft. And now I gave a try.  
# apt list minetest
# apt instsall minetest.
Anyway, it is really nice to have this alternative! Thank You!

Comment: @stefansson please take the "answer" portion of your question and place it in the "Your Answer" box below. Thank you!

Comment: Is it necessary to do that, when I think, all the information I wanted,  I gave above? (I'm just unsure.)

Comment: @stefansson yes, please. The StackExchange sites are built on the concept of Question and Answer. (These can be from the same person.)

Answer (score 2):

If you still do not have installed the Java development kit on your system:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Install Flatpack on your system:

```
sudo su
#type your admininstrator password

apt install flatpak
apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Restart your system

```
sudo reboot
```

Install the mojang.Minecraft via flatpak

```
sudo flatpak install flathub com.mojang.Minecraft
flatpak run com.mojang.Minecraft
```

Drag the Minecraft-icon into the Lounchbar upper, and you'll find next time the MC-starter there.